# ¿Cómo capturar valor seleccionado en buscador inteligente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Dispongo de un buscador inteligente, el cual he de capturar el valor en el momento que pierde el foco, pero no funciona correctamente al usar las funciones propias de jquery.

[Dejo un fiddle con el código](https://jsfiddle.net/L2a59epm/3/)

y el código suelto

```js
(function ($) {
  $.widget("ui.combobox", {
    _create: function () {

      var input, self = this,
        select = this.element.hide(),
        selected = select.children(":selected"),
        value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
        wrapper = this.wrapper = $("<span>").addClass("ui-combobox").insertAfter(select);

      input = $("<input name=ComboId id=ComboId style='height:40px;'>").appendTo(wrapper).val(value).addClass("input form-control input-lg ui-state-default ui-combobox-input").autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {

          if (request.term.length > 3) {
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");

            response(select.find("option").map(function () {
              var text = $(this).text();
              if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text))) return {
                label: text.replace(
                  new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                value: text,
                option: this,
                category: $(this).closest("optgroup").attr("label")
              };
              //MK
              $('#test').attr('style', 'display: none;');
            }).get());
          }
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
          ui.item.option.selected = true;
          self._trigger("selected", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
          });
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
          if (!ui.item) {
            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
              valid = false;
            select.children("option").each(function () {
              if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                this.selected = valid = true;

                return false;
              }
            });
            if (!valid) {
              $('#test').attr('style', 'display: block;');
            }
          }
        }
      }).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

      input.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
      };

      input.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderMenu = function (ul, items) {
        var self = this,
          currentCategory = "";

        //AÑADIDO
        //$('#loading').removeClass('hide');

        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
          if (item.category != currentCategory) {
            if (item.category) {
              ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
            }
            currentCategory = item.category;
          }
          self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
        //AÑADIDO
        //$('#loading').addClass('hide');

      };

      $("<a>").attr("tabIndex", -1).attr("title", "Ver Todos").appendTo(wrapper).button({
        icons: {
          primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
      }).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle").click(function () {
        if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
          input.autocomplete("close");
          return;
        }

        $(this).blur();

        input.autocomplete("search", "");
        input.focus();
      });
    },

    destroy: function () {
      this.wrapper.remove();
      this.element.show();
      $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);  

$(function () {
  $("#Socios").combobox();
  $("#toggle").click(function () {
    $("#Socios").toggle();
  });
});
/*****************************/
/*****************************/
/*****************************/
/*****************************/
$("#Socios").focus(function () {
  alert("focus");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="hidden" name="mostrar" id="mostrar" autocomplete="off">
    <select id="Socios" name="Socios" class="input form-control input-lg">
    <option value ="1" >111111111111</option>
    <option value ="2">222222222222</option>
    <option value ="3">33333333333</option>
    <option value ="4">4444444444444</option>
    <option value ="5">5555555555555</option>
    <option value ="6">6666666666666</option>
    <option value ="7">77777777777777</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para conseguirlo podrías valerte de la función `change` que tiene el objeto `autocomplete`.
Esta función puede recibir dos parámetros, uno de ellos es `ui` que es el objeto seleccionado del listado.

Si accedemos al `value` del `item` que tiene dicho objeto, estaríamos capturando el valor que necesitas.

```js
(function ($) {
  $.widget("ui.combobox", {
    _create: function () {
      var input, self = this,
      select = this.element.hide(),
      selected = select.children(":selected"),
      value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
      wrapper = this.wrapper = $("<span>").addClass("ui-combobox").insertAfter(select);
            
      input = $("<input name=ComboId id=ComboId style='height:40px;'>").appendTo(wrapper).val(value).addClass("input form-control input-lg ui-state-default ui-combobox-input").autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
          if (request.term.length > 3) {
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            response(select.find("option").map(function () {
              var text = $(this).text();
              
              if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text))) return {
                label: text.replace(
                  new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                value: text,
                option: this,
                category: $(this).closest("optgroup").attr("label")
              };
              
              //MK
              $('#test').attr('style', 'display: none;');
            }).get());
          }
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
          ui.item.option.selected = true;
          self._trigger("selected", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
          });
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
          alert('Valor seleccionado: ' + ui.item.value);
          
          if (!ui.item) {
            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
            valid = false;
            select.children("option").each(function () {
              if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                this.selected = valid = true;
                return false;
              }
            });
            
            if (!valid) {
              $('#test').attr('style', 'display: block;');
            }
          }
        }
      }).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

      input.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
      };

      input.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderMenu = function (ul, items) {
        var self = this,
        currentCategory = "";

        //AÑADIDO
        //$('#loading').removeClass('hide');

        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
          if (item.category != currentCategory) {
            if (item.category) {
              ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
            }
            
            currentCategory = item.category;
            
          }
          
          self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
        //AÑADIDO
        //$('#loading').addClass('hide');
      };

      $("<a>").attr("tabIndex", -1).attr("title", "Ver Todos").appendTo(wrapper).button({
        icons: {
          primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
      }).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle").click(function () {
        if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
          input.autocomplete("close");
          return;
        }

        $(this).blur();
        input.autocomplete("search", "");
        input.focus();
      });
    },
    destroy: function () {
      this.wrapper.remove();
      this.element.show();
      $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);  

$(function () {
  $("#Socios").combobox();
  $("#toggle").click(function () {
    $("#Socios").toggle();
  });
});

/*****************************/
/*****************************/
/*****************************/
/*****************************/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control input-lg" type="hidden" name="mostrar" id="mostrar" autocomplete="off">

<select id="Socios" name="Socios" class="input form-control input-lg">
  <option value ="1" >111111111111</option>
  <option value ="2">222222222222</option>
  <option value ="3">33333333333</option>
  <option value ="4">4444444444444</option>
  <option value ="5">5555555555555</option>
  <option value ="6">6666666666666</option>
  <option value ="7">77777777777777</option>
</select>
```